# passing variables through parameters AJAX PHP JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to write a simple AJAX code to get it to search through a simple array, and output the results to the screen, and it works before I tried to pass the variables through the parameter, but now it isn't passing the variables through the parameters for some reason. Please take a look:

> functions.js:

```
var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();

//****************************************************************AJAX

function createXmlHttpRequestObject() {
    var xmlHttp;

    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            xmlHttp = false;
        }
    } else {
        try {
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch (e) {
            xmlHttp = false;
        }
    }

    if (!xmlHttp)
        alert("Not xmlHttp!")else
            return xmlHttp;
}

//****************************************************************AJAX

function process(IDName, passTo, output) {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 0 || xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
        get = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById(IDName).value);
        xmlHttp.open("GET", passTo + get, true);
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse(output);
        xmlHttp.send(null);
    } else {
        setTimeout('process()', 1000);
    }
}

//****************************************************************AJAX

function handleServerResponse(output) {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
        if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
            xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
            xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;
            message = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;
            document.getElementById(output).innerHTML = message;
            setTimeout('process()', 1000);
        } else {
            alert('xmlHttp.status does not equal 200!');
        }
    }
}
```

> foodstore.php:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>';

echo '<response>';
$food = $_GET['food'];
$foodArray = array('tuna','bacon','beef','ham');

if(in_array($food,$foodArray))
    echo 'We do have '.$food.'!';
elseif ($food=='')
    echo 'Enter a food';
else
   echo 'Sorry punk we dont sell no '.$food.'!';

echo '</response>';
?>
```

> test5.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="process('userInput','foodstore.php?food=','underInput')">
    <h3>The Chuff Bucker</h3>
    Enter the food you would like to order:
    <input type="text" id="userInput" />
    <div id="underInput" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Frankly, and while an aside from the question, why not use one of the _many many_ JS libraries out there that will do most of this for you?

Comment: @JonStirling JS libraries?

Comment: jQuery, Angular, MooTools. The list goes on.

Comment: jQuery.  You can just use the jQuery ajax method. Very simple to use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `console.log(variable)` on different stages to check the current state of variables, probably you are having problems with the `get` variable with the `encodeURIComponent` or maybe it isn't entering to that `if` on process function.